# How to find the sub child in Firebase in Java Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have seen a couple of answers, But I didn't get help from those! Might be I am wrong. But here I am trying to find the item `where key = user_id` inside `split_management`.
Below is the image!

[image]

And below is the code which is not working as expected!

```
public synchronized void fetchGroups(final IConstants.CallBack callBack) {
    Models.User model = AppController.instance.getUser();
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = database.getReference();
    Query query = mDatabaseReference.child(IConstants.DBReference.split_management).orderByChild(model.getUid());
    query.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildKey) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                if (callBack != null) {
                    Models.Group group = dataSnapshot.getValue(Models.Group.class);
                    callBack.callBack(group);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (callBack != null) {
                callBack.callBack(IConstants.Key.updated);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (callBack != null) {
                callBack.callBack(IConstants.Key.updated);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (callBack != null) {
                callBack.callBack(IConstants.Key.updated);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            if (callBack != null) {
                callBack.callBack(null);
            }
        }
    });
```

I am not getting proper output! I will very thank full to you all if you could provide me a solution for this! I want resultant query like - **Fetch record where key(Which is inside random) = 'SOME_KEY'(Which is User ID)**

Comment: What output are you getting vs. what are you expecting?

Comment: With this I am getting all the record. Where user_id also not exist as key! Those records also coming!

Comment: Ah yes, you have to filter those `null` values out. See my answer below.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Yes it is solved! @AlexMamo by the given answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter out `null` values returned in your query results by specifying a start value of `false`:

```java
 Query query = mDatabaseReference.child(IConstants.DBReference.split_management).orderByChild(model.getUid()).startAt(false);
```

See [How query data is ordered](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order) for why `false` was used here.

However, this query is ill-advised as it requires the client to perform the sort as the data is not indexable. I would advise keeping a list of all `split_management` IDs linked to the desired user in `/users/someUserId/split_management_ids` or similar, like so:

```js
{
  "/users/someUserId/split_management_ids": {
    "251219141300803": true,
    "564634584234535": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Here you means to say that, Create split id record inside user records? Is that right Sir!

Comment: If you don't want to download your entire database under `/split_management` on every query, yes. It will also be significantly faster to get the list of IDs and then fetch each `/split_management/someSplitId/someUserId`

Comment: Ok, But I have tried above query! The Above query also returning expected result! is that query can create problem in future or it is fine?

Comment: If the query above works, it is because your data set is small. But as the number of users grows and entries under `/split_management` increases, it will become more expensive to use that query. Using a custom index will provide the most cost-effective solution.

Comment: Ok, Then I will try with second solution! Thanks for the help!